# Unable to connect CVS repository from eclipse

Tags: ssh, eclipse, cvs

I am getting error while connecting to CVS repository from eclipse running on Windows 7. I am connecting using ext method. Below is the error I am getting:

> Could not connect to :ext:username@servername:/CVSROOT_PATH: I/O exception occurred: Cannot run program "ssh": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>   Cannot run program "ssh": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution. Type the below commands in your shell.

```
export CVS_RSH=ssh
export CVS_SERVER=/home/xxx/cvs/src/cvs
```

CVS_SERVER value can be obtained by typing `which cvs` cmd in your shell)

```
cvs -d :ext:userid@server:CVSROOT_PATH checkout appName
```

Make the necessary changes and then commit the changes using below command

```
cvs -d :ext:userid@server:CVSROOT_PATH commit appName
```